# Wordpress, Add Rewrite Rule to a custom URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, addition, rules

I need to get an URL for a json file as: https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json

So I Added the add_rewrite_rule function as:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^.well-known/assetlinks.json$','index.php?asset-link=assetlinks', 'top' );
```

But I can not get an satisfying resulto on my end, could you please help me to get the error on the script?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a working link and a link you want as end result? It is not clear from the question what exactly you want to rewrite and to what.

Comment: Sure, here the URL working:

http://asociacionlosmiradores.com.ar/well-known/assetlinks.json/

but, I need two Updates, first I need print the URL as:

http://asociacionlosmiradores.com.ar/.well-known/assetlinks.json

With a "dot" before well-known and without the final "/" after assetlinks.json

Comment: I used the Rule as:
`add_rewrite_rule( '^well-known/(.*)?','index.php?asset-link=assetlinks', 'top' );`

Comment: Your server is Apache based or Nginx based?

Comment: The server is Nginx Based

Comment: Do you have access to Nginx configurations?

Comment: nope, I can't get access to the config :(

Comment: Then we'll need to do it via htaccess somehow.

Comment: Try this:          RewriteRule "(^|/)\.(?!well-known\/)" - [F]               in .htaccess file

Comment: I have my scripts on vip go, I can't access to htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for this Question:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^\.well-known\/(.*)?','index.php?asset-link=assetlinks', 'top' );
```

This can to you print an json file in wordpress as:
https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json/

As required on:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#publish-json

THanks!